# TFS Global List in Database

Tags: tfs

I have TFS2010 and I am wondering, where can I find the global list values within the TFS database. I am trying to find the correct table name and database that contains the values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't support using the operational data store, instead use the API's we provide to you. To start using the API for global list see http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2010/03/08/tfs-api-part-23-create-global-list-xml-way.aspx

Comment: I do have another question. Is there a table within the TFS database that contains change set numbers? My goal is to create a query such that I am able to pull up a user, the change sets he/she has worked on, and the files associated with those change sets

Comment: I don't have the tablename, but you can find it pretty easy in the TFSWarehouse database. We don't support querying the operational datastore (it can and will be changed every release, while the TFSWarehouse is documented and if possible backwards compatible)